# Xcode Button to Launch URL

Tags: xcode, button

I've created a simple app that has a button in the bottom toolbar and I can't seem to get the button to work. I've tried to attach an action to it that will open a URL when pressed but it did not work. So I've removed that action and I'm hoping someone can help. I've posted the compressed xcode project at this URL https://www.box.com/s/5d45ce1df7d9dd0fe205

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Something like this would work. This is an example of a text-only button:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button setTitle:@"Google" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(openGoogleURL) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And the button's selector:

```
-(void)openGoogleURL
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use another viewcontroller with webView embeeded. 
This solution force to stay in your application during watching url content.

1. Create another view controller on storyboard.
2. place webview on it. ( name it webView )
3. connect web view with controller class through assistant editor ( assuming that You connected new UIView class to view controller )
4. in viewDidLoad of your new class insert:

   ```
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.pl";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
   ```